# accessing column_types in pymssql connection class

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7, sqldatatypes, pymssql

I am using the pymssql module. And I am trying to extract the datatypes of my columns. According to the [github code](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/blob/master/src/_mssql.pyx#L567) it should be possible to access it by `connection.column_types` But I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: '_mssql.MSSQLConnection' object has no attribute 'column_types'
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I have the right object, I am creating my connection with the `_mssql.connect()` method:

```
pymssql._mssql.connect(server=HOST, port=PORT, user=USR, password=PWD, **KWARGS)
```

(But even when I am using the DBAPI connect() method `pymssql.connect()`:

```
pymssql.connect(host=HOST, port=PORT, user=USR, password=PWD, **KWARGS)
```

And then I try to access the underlying connection class `cursor._source._conn.column_types` it also fails for the same reason:

```
AttributeError: '_mssql.MSSQLConnection' object has no attribute 'column_types'
```

**How can I get the data types?**

Comment: It appears that the `column_types` reference in the source code doesn't mean what you think it does. However, there's data type information available from the [.description](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#description) attribute of a Cursor object. You could also run a query against the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` view.

Comment: @GordThompson Can you please elaborate? You could easily turn your knowledge into a good answer for me it seems. The description doesn't contain enough information, it's abstracted I need the raw-est form of datatype. `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` Doesn't help me, I want the types in the resultset, not on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened a ticket on the github, and it [got an answer](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/480#issuecomment-281409225). Posting here for posterity and completeness.

> `column_types` is `cdef` so only accessible from C code, not Python.

It's not what I was hoping for, but alas, it is the answer.